# Controlling frame rate in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I am working on a project using SpriteKit to present simple shapes (SKShapeNode and SKSpriteNode) on the screen and move these shapes around in a predefined way.
I am interested in obtaining a very smooth motion, even for fast moving shapes (The code runs smooth for a couple of hundreds shapes and most of the time I only need less than 10).

I am quite satisfied with the motion smoothness for slowly moving objects on my macbook air and imac (60Hz displays and 60fps reported by showFPS in the SKView), however fast moving shapes create artefacts.

For that reason I would like to display the scene on a 120Hz monitor. I have scoured stackoverflow for a solution and only found solution to reduce the framerate from 60fps to 30 and 15 fps using frameInterval, but I haven't worked out how to obtain something higher than 60fps.

I have tried connecting my mac to a 85Hz CRT monitor (refresh rate set up in System Preferences to 85Hz), but my SKView still runs at 60fps.
Is there a way to access the EDID information of the monitor programmatically through SpriteKit? Is it possible to run an SKView at more than 60fps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the reply. Would you recommend some Apple documentation regarding this?

Comment: The Apple docs for SKView used to include 60 for the frameInterval max but this has seemed to have been deleted now.

Comment: Thanks. Using google to search specifically the tech notes from the apple developer for documentation mentioning the vsync, I only found something regarding openGL:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2093/_index.html  
_The refresh rate on LCD displays refers generally to frame rate, which is typically a fixed rate of 60Hz._  

Not specific to SpriteKit, but the philosophy may apply.